# Binding ItemSource property in a custom control that contains a Picker

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, wpf-controls

I'm trying to create a custom control that contains a Picker With Xamarin.Forms.
the problem is when trying to bind the ItemSource property, it's never gets binded, and when I touch the custom control on the mobile it shows an empty dialog with no binded items.

**Note**: I tried almost every solution I found on "Stack OverFlow" or on "forums.xamarin", and none of them worked for me.

here's my code:

For the Custom Control XAML file - which's named with "HitPicker" -  :

```
   <Picker x:Name="PickerField" 
        HeightRequest="46" 
        TitleColor="{Binding TitleColor}"
        TextColor="{Binding TextColor}" 
        BackgroundColor="{Binding BackgroundColor}"
        Unfocused="Handle_Unfocused" 
        Focused="Handle_Focused"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource}">
   </Picker>
```

For Custom Control cs File:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsSourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create("ItemsSource", typeof(List<string>), typeof(HitPicker), default(List<string>), BindingMode.TwoWay, null, OnItemsSourceChanged);

public List<string> ItemsSource
    {
        get => (List<string>)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty);
        set => SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
    }

public HitPicker()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = this;
}

private static void OnItemsSourceChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldvalue, object newvalue)
    {
        var picker = (bindable as HitPicker).PickerField;
        picker.Items.Clear();
        var newList = newvalue as List<string>;
        if (newvalue != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in newList)
            {
                picker.Items.Add(item.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

knowing that OnItemsSourceChanged method is never called, and almost every similar question to mine is answered with a similar answer, that suggests putting this method in the control class.

for XAML file that uses this control:

```
<controls:HitPicker ItemsSource="{Binding MonkeyList}" Title="Select monky" BackgroundColor="Azure"></controls:HitPicker>
```

and here's the monkey list declaration in the ViewModel for the above XAML:

```
 private List<string> _lst = new List<string>{
            "Baboon",
            "Capuchin Monkey",
            "Blue Monkey",
            "Squirrel Monkey",
            "Golden Lion Tamarin",
            "Howler Monkey",
            "Japanese Macaque"
        };

    public List<string> MonkeyList
    {
        get => _lst;
        set
        {
            _lst = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

MonkeyList getter is never called too, knowing that the Binding context is the ViewModel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set the bindingcontext in CustomControl like

```
public HitPicker()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = this;
}
```

It will break the binding between custom control and ContentPage .

So you could modify the code like following

#### in HitPicker.xaml

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            //...
             x:Name="pickerView" //set name of page >
```

```
   <Picker x:Name="PickerField" 
        HeightRequest="46" 
        TitleColor="{Binding Source={x:Reference pickerView}, Path=TitleColor}"
        TextColor="{Binding Source={x:Reference pickerView}, Path=TextColor}" 
        BackgroundColor="{Binding Source={x:Reference pickerView}, Path=BackgroundColor}"
        Unfocused="Handle_Unfocused" 
        Focused="Handle_Focused"
        SelectedItem="{Binding Source={x:Reference pickerView}, Path=SelectedItem}">
   </Picker>
```

#### in HitPicker.xaml.cs

```
public HitPicker()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //BindingContext = this;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, can you give refereces for issues like this, or from where did you know that setting BindingContext  will breake the binding.

And please if you can edit your answer to tell to remove OnItemsSourceChanged method, becuase it throws exeption when modifying Picker Items if the ItemSource property is set.

Comment: You just need to remove it directly .When we set the ItemSource as a bindable property , it will been changed auto when we set it in ViewModel (so we don't need to add it manually) .

Comment: My comment is separated into two parts. Sorry, you may misunderstand me

Comment: You just need to remove OnItemsSourceChanged  directly .

Comment: For the first part , you could check https://www.xamarinhelp.com/bindable-properties-xamarin-forms/ . In the blog the demo code without using data binding in custom control (set the value directly in code behind).So if you do want to use data binding , you need set the binding path directly like the above code .

Comment: Oh, ok it's me the one who misunderstands you. thanks

Comment: excuse me, it works the first time but now it's throwing the following exception:{Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 10:18. Can not find the object referenced by `hitPickerView`
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ReferenceExtension.ProvideValue (System.IServiceProvider serviceProvider) [0x000bf] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\MarkupExtensions\ReferenceExtension.cs:42 
  at UiTestApp.Controls.HitPicker.InitializeComponent () [0x00045].......the complement in the next comment

Comment: in C:\Projects\UiTest\UiTest\UiTest\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\Controls\HitPicker.xaml.g.cs:34 
  at UiTestApp.Controls.HitPicker..ctor () [0x00021] in C:\Projects\UiTest\UiTest\UiTest\Controls\HitPicker.xaml.cs:93 }

Comment: in another custom control, it's solved by setting the BindingContext the way that is in the post.

Comment: You could share your sample to github and I will have a check  .

Comment: Here are some similar issue that you can have a refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64212190/include-dynamic-custom-xamarin-xaml-view-control/64218483#64218483    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64353025/how-to-bind-an-itemssource-from-a-collectionview-in-a-custom-control/64354267#64354267    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64116686/how-to-bind-a-commandparameter-in-a-contentview-to-an-element-in-the-parent-cont/64118136#64118136

Comment: Sorry for beeing late it's my first time using git in visual studio. here's the [GitHub link](https://github.com/TameemHabash/Xamarin-Custom-Controls) ....for your answers they are just like I did when you answered the question.

Comment: Is there any resource to learn how to create custom controls?....there is a lot I need to learn, as you see HitPicker And HitEntry are a copy-past code from the internet, I'm really in need to learn how to biuld controls and thier renderers.